# Creating random numbers within a range

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and I am stuck on this, I am using the formula:

```
min + (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1))
```

and I have to write statements that assign random integers to the variable x in the following ranges

1. `1 < x <= 8`
   1 being min and 8 being max

   Am I correct that it would be `1 + (int)(Math.random()*(8-1+1))`?
2. `-5 < x <= 3`
   3 being min and -5 being max

   and this would be `3 + (int)(Math.radom()*(-5-3+1))`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: have you tried running your code with what you have written? [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) gives you a random number between 0 and 1, the rest should be easy

Comment: A search of SO reveals this as first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/791406

Comment: Substitute `0`, then `1`, as `Math.random()` and see what you get.

Comment: You need to check your math, me thinks... `(Math.random()*(8-1+1))` is no different than `Math.random()*7`. I'm not saying it's wrong, just... excessive.

Comment: @Dukeling I think you mean substitute 0 and 1 as that's the range for `Math.random()`.

Comment: @Shaded So what would you simplify `max - min + 1` to? Your comment doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Shaded Oh, right, yes.

Comment: @DuncanJones Ah you're right, if you just plugging in for the initial equation, I thought he was hardcoding those values. My mistake, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3):

You want a formula to take a real number in the range `[0..1)`, and return an integer in the range `[1..8]`.

- When `random()` picks a real number it the range `[0..1)`,
- and you multiply it by 8,
- you get a value in the range `[0.0 .. 8.0)`.
- Then you then convert to `(int)`, you have an integer in the range `[0 .. 7]`,
- because conversion to `(int)` rounds using the 'floor' step function.
- Add one.

Answer (score 0):

use following code. It will generate nos between 0 and max value supplied.

```
 Random generator = new Random(); //Creates a new random number generator
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
      /**
       *Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value
       * between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from
       * this random number generator's sequence
       */
        System.out.println(generator.nextInt(100));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get random value with range **(** min, max **]** , this is the same with the question.

If **JDK 1.7** version is used, then you can use one line code to implement such function:

**ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max)+1**

If JDK version is under 1.7, we can implement it using the following way.

Random random = new Random();

**random.nextInt(max - min) + min +1;**

2.Get random value with range **[** min, max **)**

Use,
**ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max)**

or

**random.nextInt(max - min) + min ;**

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() gives you between 0 and 1. Multiply this by your range, the size of the range, not the absolute value. If you want 1-10 that's 9, if you want 0-10 that's 10, if you want 5-7 that's 2, etc.

Then add or subtract to go from 0 to the starting value.

If you want 0-9 then you're done (you should have multiplied by 9 in the previous step)

If you want 1-10 then add 1

If you want -5 to 5 then subtract 5

If you want 5-7 then do (Math.random()*2)+5;